# How do I make Bootstrap Select2 dropdown go to the selected URL on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 (https://select2.github.io) and I'm trying to make it go directly to a specific URL instead of using it as a form. So if someone clicks Alabama, it will go to alabama.com and if someone clicks Wyoming then wyoming.com, etc.

The form is pretty basic, like:

```
<form>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select> 
</form>
```

Initiated with

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
});
```

I've searched for an onclick method but there doesn't seem to be one. I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbwcffcm/1/

Has anyone managed to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select2 has custom events, including one called [select2:select](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#events).

> `select2:select` is fired whenever a result is selected.

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
}).on('select2:select', function(){
    switch($(this).val())
    {
        case 'AL':
            location.href = 'http://www.alabama.com';
            break;
        case 'WY':
            location.href = 'http://www.wyoming.com';
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: How could this edited so that instead of going to seperate external URLs, it can go to relative URLs, including a value from the list object? For example my list contains entries such as `Grace (1234)` and `Sarah (5678)` etc. I'd like the URLs to be `/readers/1234/` and `/readers/5678/` etc, when clicked.